# Playing embedded YouTube video in landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, youtube, ios6, embedded-resource

I recently started updating one of my apps to iOS6. Everything was went sort of smooth until I stumbled across the "new" way to embedd YouTube videos in a UIWebView as can be read here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

The problem is my app is Portrait only but the videos would obviously benefit from playing fullscreen in landscape mode. This mix worked fine pre iOS6 (at least for me, could possible be since iOS5) but now using the new `<iframe>` stuff it is stuck in a small portrait view.

Anyone had this problem and a possible fix?